# ios simulator appear with UDID in xcode 6

Tags: iphone, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6gm

When i select simulator from xcode 6 then i'm getting multiple option to select simulator but simulator comes with UDID. Please see the below image and please help me out. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode using GUID instead of iOS version number in Simulator Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533025/xcode-using-guid-instead-of-ios-version-number-in-simulator-selection)

Answer (score 40):

> `killall Xcode`
>
>  - Kills all running Xcode processes.
>
> `sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`
>
> - Kills all running CoreSimulatorService's processes.
>
> `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`
>
> - Removes all Simulator data, from all the Simulators.
>
> `open /Applications/Xcode.app` - Opens Xcode.

---

The above steps from xcode 10 are invalid, please use the following steps:

`xcrun simctl shutdown all`
shutdown all devices

`xcrun simctl list devices|grep -v "unavailable"|grep -Eo "[0-9A-F\-]{36}"`
list all available devices

`xcrun simctl list devices|grep -v "unavailable"|grep -Eo "[0-9A-F\-]{36}"|xargs xcrun simctl delete` 
delete all devices(note: this is a single line)

more detail `xcrun simctl help`

Comment: killing processes in my case was required in order to fix the issue. being done solely from terminal is pretty neat, though

Comment: This answer should be updated with an explanation of the causes of the issue, and an explanation of what the terminal commands do.

Comment: That worked, but now I have no simulators. How do I get a base set of simulators back again? The Downloads window doesn't list the iOS 9.2 simulator, and shows the others as already downloaded.

Comment: I found it: Window > Devices > + > Add Simulator.

Answer (score 21):

In Xcode, go to Window -> Devices (shortcut is Cmd+!)

In the left pane, delete all the superfluous simulator devices (select in the left pane and press delete on keyboard)

Usually these are the ones that have no OS (showing iOS: n/a).

This usually happens when you try and copy older simulator versions directly in the SDK folders rather than installing them from Xcode -> Preferences.

Comment: Ok, Thanks but it i want to copy old simulator then how to do it??

Comment: you shouldn't copy it directly. Go to Preferences -> Downloads and under Components, download the simulator that you need.

Answer (score 16):

**How to fix it**

Xcode uses the device version to disambiguate devices with the same name.
If two devices have the same name and version number, it will use the devices' UDIDs.

You have 4 of each of a bunch of devices (eg iPhone 5s).  I suspect that some of them are for the same iOS version.  You should delete some of the duplicates.  Check out `xcrun simctl list` and `xcrun simctl delete` or use the device manager within Xcode.app (click on the "-" to delete a device).

**How to just get back to a default state**

```
# Ensure all possible clients of CoreSimulatorService are no longer running:

killall Xcode 2> /dev/null
killall Instruments 2> /dev/null
killall 'iOS Simulator' 2> /dev/null
killall Simulator 2> /dev/null
killall 'Simulator (Watch)' 2> /dev/null
killall ibtoold 2> /dev/null
killall simctl 2> /dev/null
# There may be others

# Kill the service itself
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService

# Remove all the data and logs
rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator
```

**Why this might be happening:**

CoreSimulatorService will monitor for the addition of new simulator runtimes in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles (eg, for when downloading them from Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads).  When installing a new runtime, CoreSimulatorService will create an initial set of devices for that runtime.

This problem arrises if there are multiple instances of CoreSimulatorService running at the same time.  Each CoreSimulatorService instance will create its own set of devices (but its clients will only see that instances's sets at first).  On subsequent launches (eg: after a reboot), both copies will be seen.  One can get into a state where multiple copies of CoreSimulatorService are running at the same time due to testing beta versions of Xcode.app in the same login session as using the released Xcode.app or by having used Xcode.app before and after updating it through the App Store.

If you are aware of any other way that this bug might come about, please file a new radar at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I've deleted all files in ~/Devices/ folder. But still getting this one.

Comment: You would need to SIGKILL the service ss well (or just reboot).

Comment: Other solutions didn't work but this one did.  The `*` was key for me  because `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator` needs to be deleted as well.

Comment: This works for me. Others didn't fully resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @ameer-sheikh mentioned, go to Window > Devices
You likely have multiple devices with the same iOS version.  I had the same issue, and after selecting each duplicate device and pressing delete I was able to restore order to my Devices dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Devices (Shortcut is Cmd+Shift+2)
In the left pane, delete all the superfluous simulator devices (select in the left pane and press delete on keyboard)
Usually these are the ones that have no OS (showing iOS: n/a).
This usually happens when you try and copy older simulator versions directly in the SDK folders rather than installing them from Xcode -> Preferences.

Answer (score -1):

The bash commands in another answer are probably simpler but you can try this for an easier yet more complex solution:

`gem install snapshot; snapshot reset_simulators`

https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot

via @saniul

Comment: Though when I do this it removes all my sims from my beta Xcode 7 install and my Xcode 7 sim crashes on launch because it assumes at least one sim is installed. I had to create an Xcode 7 sim in the devices window.