# Xcode scheme craziness

Tags: xcode

I've been using essentially the same set of schemes for my app for several years with no problem. When selecting a scheme to build, for each simulator device there would be a choice of iOS reflecting what simulators were installed.

Trying to solve a problem, I deleted Derived Data per some suggestions here. Today, when I select a scheme to build, I get this:

[image]

This is not helpful! I cannot figure out how to get back to the Target/Scheme combinations I had before. Any and all help will be appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode using GUID instead of iOS version number in Simulator Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533025/xcode-using-guid-instead-of-ios-version-number-in-simulator-selection)

Answer (score 0):

yes i got this when I installed Xcode 7 beta.

Went away when I downloaded XCode 7 from the mac app store.

But I had to run Xcode 6.4 to test swift 1.2 code and was fine for a while till i rang two simulators at once.

Then in Xcode 7 they all appeared again

I had also downloaded the 8.4 simulator in Xcode 7 today so this may also have caused it.

---

I believe both simulators were sharing this folder so they got merged:
/Users/gbxc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
/Users/gbxc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/device_set.plist

raised q:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742962/xcode-devices-list-showing-50-devices