# How do I know the iOS version of the simulator when choosing?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, version

My Xcode works fine with me except when choosing simulator, as the picture shows, I can't know the iOS version of the simulator. Any idea? [Here is the picture, no place to find out iOS version]

[image]

Comment: Please search before asking a question.  This has been asked multiple times before.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia.Duplicated indeed, I failed to search out that question yesterday, thanks for pointing out and pasting the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down to the bottom of that list of simulators in the provided screenshot there should be a button entitled `Add Additional Simulators...` click on that and it will (does for me) show you the OS version of all simulators and any connected devices.

**EDIT** Here is another thing that should probably work. As you can see from the image you provided there are duplicates of each simulator. What you have to do is go in and delete the duplicates. You do this by again clicking on the `Add Additional Simulators...` button right clicking on the duplicates and pressing delete. Do this for all the duplicates and it should then show the OS version.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but I used to see iOS version directly in that list, just like "iPhone 6( iOS 9.2 )", all I want is just have it back instead of what in the picture.

Comment: @SherlockOy I edited my answer.

Comment: The question seems to duplicated of [XCode using GUID instead of iOS version number in Simulator Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533025/xcode-using-guid-instead-of-ios-version-number-in-simulator-selection). Yet still thanks.