# Xcode Simulators: How to recreate simulators automatically?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

My XCode simulators names started appearing with simulators identifiers (like `iPad Air - xxxxxxxxxxxxx`) instead of iOS versions in simulator selections menu, How can I fix it correctly?

Is there anyway to recreate all simulators automatically?

Thanks,

Comment: Hope this answers your query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274517/simulator-name-is-shown-with-id-instead-of-os-name-in-xcode-6-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Script to recreate XCode Simulators**

I found following solution to recreate XCode simulators automatically and its works like a charm.

For XCode7 : https://gist.github.com/cabeca/3ff77007204e5479f7af

For XCode 6 : https://gist.github.com/cabeca/cbaacbeb6a1cc4683aa5

**Steps to run script:**

```
1- Copy and past script in a file, name it 'resetSims.rb'
2- Run script in terminal by using command : ruby /Users/xxx/Desktop/resetSims.rb
```

Ref : 
[How to execute a Ruby script in Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721369/how-to-execute-a-ruby-script-in-terminal)