# Weird Strings for iOS version in Xcode simulator list

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

As you can see in the screenshot, I am getting this weird string for some simulators. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I am seeing the same thing as of today - did you ever find a fix?

Comment: No still looking for a fix. Post here if u find please.

Comment: I delete duplicated entries (ex: iPhone 5s (7.1)) and it works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to @stevechen for pointing me in the right direction, I finally solved this problem :

1. Xcode Menu > Open Developer Tools > Open iOS Simulator
2. iOS Simulator Menu > Hardware > Device > Manage Devices
3. Delete all the bad entries
4. Add then back

Enjoy!

Answer (score 34):

It happened to me,when there were both Xcode7-beta and Xcode6 in my Mac.
As you see,UDID-like strings are UDIDs (Unique Device IDentification numbers) for the iOS Simulator devices. As they are duplicated devices with unique UDIDs,to  there are two ways to solve this problem,:

1. I suspect the issue will go away if you restart the service:
   Quit Xcode, Instruments, and the iOS Simulator and then run this in Terminal.app:

   ```
   sudo killall -9 Xcode 'iOS Simulator' com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
   ```

   Then

   ```
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
   ```
2. Just change and rename your simulators: In xCode go to Window -> Devices and press the plus in the bottom corner and add the simulators that you wish or minus to remove.

[image]

Then it'll be ok:
[image]

Comment: I had almost 1000 simulator entries, so option 1 was best for me!

Answer (score 5):

I ended up running this:

```
killall Xcode

sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService

rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

open /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Per this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31421158/406

It worked great for me!

Xcode 6.4