# XCode 6.4 device list corrupted

Tags: ios, xcode

Since adding iOS8.3 or 8.4 simulators, my device list in XCode 6 is filled with UDIDs instead of iOS version.  Adding the 8.4 sim to the new Xcode 7 beta seems to have created a similar issue.

[image]

Comment: Happened to me as well. Luckily, they're still sorted by device name, then iOS version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211593/ios-simulator-appear-with-udid-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 0):

In the device list (Window > Devices) there were multiple devices with the same iOS version.
After deleting each duplicate device I was able to restore order to my Devices dropdown.
Seems to be a bug with the iOS8.4 sim, as I had duplicates for all of my iOS8.4 devices