# How to identify iOS 8 and iOS 9 simulators in iPhoneSimulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I have downloaded iOS 8.4 simulator in XCode 7.1. But in my simulator list lot of simulator names shown? How do identify the iOS 9 and iOS 8 simulator ? [image]

Comment: verry funny bug :D, try to reinstall your xcode :))

Comment: Is this xcode bug ? Every time I got like that in Xcode 7.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios simulator appear with UDID in xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211593/ios-simulator-appear-with-udid-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try going to Xcode ~> Window ~> Devices

And then either:

- delete or rename (right click on simulator of interest)
- add a new simulator (click the <kbd>+</kbd> button in left-bottom corner). You can choose iOS version, device type, add custom name to it, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click Simulator First then Click the window option in tool bar that shows the simulator details.

> Click -->Simulator --> Window(ToolBar)

Comment: How do I know in the XCode ? Is there any way to identify the iOS 8 and iOS 9 simulators ?