# XCode 8 GM schemes listing massive

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently learning so I don't know all the correct names for items, but when I downloaded the Xcode 8 beta, it showed a massive list of various iOS devices that I could virtually test on.  When I asked a developer friend about it, he said that his didn't look anything like mine.  I have uninstalled both Xcode 7 and 8 beta and installed the 8 gold version and the list of devices is still massive.

Can someone tell me where I go or how to trim this list down.  I would also like to get rid of the extra "name".

Here's the screenshot of what I'm talking about.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/h745l.png

Comment: Go to Window > Devices in Xcode and delete all the duplicate ones from the simulators list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios simulator appear with UDID in xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211593/ios-simulator-appear-with-udid-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Dan above.

> Go to Window > Devices in Xcode and delete all the duplicate ones from the simulators list