# Missing simulators in xcode 9.4.1

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9.4

> 

I am currently running 2 versions of xcode. I recently upgraded from 
    9.3 to 9.4.1 and also xcode 10 beta 6 on High Sierra v.10.13.6. The 
    simulators seem to work fine in xcode 10 beta 6 but are completely 
    missing from 9.4.1 I have downloaded and installed additional 
    simulators which show up in the simulators window list, however they 
    are not added to the drop downs in the main project window and the devices list remains empty. I wondered 
    if its simply that I have messed up something in the installation. I 
    have tried to remove everything and reinstall and got the same problem.

> 

Any advice would be great. If anyone who is also running two versions could recommend 
    also optimum set up with installation etc.  I can 
    post more detail as required. I have added screen shots please follow 
    the links.

```
 [main nav - generic iOS device][1]
 [empty devices panel][2]
 [simulators panel][3]

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qU4M.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVLo0.png
 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vavl1.png
```

Comment: did you `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode10.app`

Comment: REALLY stupid suggestion, but uninstall/reinstall? (I'm old school - if all else fails reboot.)

Comment: thanks for your replies - i have tried uninstall and reinstall but still cant get all the simulators to load i have found other people with similar problems with earlier versions but not 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. If I created a new account on the same system that new account did not have the same issues. This lead me to believe it was a user preferences issue.

Some of the advice for fixing this involves deleting all Xcode files and re-installing from scratch. Try the solution below to see if it works for you since it’s much faster and less work.

- Quit any running version of Xcode
- Delete the folder: ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator

You can see from the attached screen shot there is a device_set.plist file. Deleting this file alone doesn’t help so delete the entire directory it’s inside of.

- Launch Xcode
- Select Preferences and go to the “Components” tab.
- Download ANY new simulator

Once downloaded you should see all of your simulators showing up. It seems to be the process of downloading a new simulator rebuilds the list of installed simulators.

Note I tried downloading a new simulator w/out throwing away the above directory to see if this would rebuild the list of simulators but it did not work.

[image: Simulator List]

Comment: Here's another really great link if the above doesn't help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26217806/3343808